# Deploy Openapi YAML config to Google Endpoint with $ref

Tags: yaml, openapi, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

Is it possible to deploy Openapi YAML config to Google Endpoints if it references from multiple files, having the files stored in a folder structure?

For example:

```
-\ openapi.yaml
--\service1\service1.yaml
--\service2\service2.yaml
.
.
.
```

Let's say openapi.yaml has $ref to one or more definitions within service1.yaml and service2.yaml.

Please note that I have a big number of folders and YAMLs, and the above is just an example of what I am trying to achieve.

How can I deploy this structure as-is to Google Endpoints using service-management?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Endpoints' support for OpenAPI [doesn't handle](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/openapi-limitations#external_type_references) external type references. Even if it did, the path structure is not preserved during the OpenAPI upload in `gcloud endpoints services deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you could use [speccy](https://speccy.io/) for this task. It merges your api description with all your references into on single deployable yaml file.
`speccy resolve openapi-template.yaml -j -o openapi.yaml`
You can even merge json references into your yaml file by adding the `-j` flag.

Speccy is a npm package, so, you would obviously need an node.js environment to use it.